# Handling PDF result data from ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf-generation

I wondered if anyone could suggest an alternative approach to the following work around.

I have a web application that makes an http request for a PDF. The PDF can take more than the default timeout for a request to be created server side, so to better control this, I have used ajax, where as previously just window.open had been used.

However, because of how the PDF is prepared, the request to create it, also returns it. I couldnt work out a way to handle the binary PDF data returned so I simply rellied on the browsers cache to store the data. Then simply requested against the same url again, but using window.open.

The code for this is as follows..

```
function loadPdf(url, timeout){
   $.ajax({
     url: url,
     success: function(data){
       window.open(url);
     },
     error: function(error, status){
       window.alert("Problem retrieving PDF.\nThe error status is: " + status);
     },
     timeout: timeout,
     dataType: "application/pdf"   
  });
}
```

Really what I would like to do is handle the success data in a way that asks the user to open/save the PDF. I dont really like to use window.open in this way, especially as a repeat call like this.

Comment: Maybe something with iframes?

Comment: Thats something I had considered, and possibly an option going forward.

Answer (score 2):

> Really what I would like to do is handle the success data in a way
>   that asks the user to open/save the PDF

That's impossible. You should not use AJAX to download files. You can't do anything useful with the byte array that you retrieved in the `success` callback. You can't directly save it on the client computer (for obvious reasons) and you can't prompt the user with the Save dialog neither.

You don't need to use `window.open` either. You could simply provide a link to the file:

```
<a href="/somescript">download pdf</a>
```

and then on the server specify the: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf"` custom HTTP header to show the save dialog allowing the user to specify a location on his computer to store the file.

Comment: I have made the Content-Disposition change server side, which has improved things. I cant currently just use a link, but I am planning to try a code refactor to make that possible. I dont currently know how to handle a timeout value through a link, which is really the main problem. ALso just to clarify, I never intended to save data to the users pc, I was talking about the default dialog you mention in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would the [jquery.fileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) plugin do what you need?